# Why doesn't PRTG see as many OIDs as MIB Browser does?

Tags: snmp

I used iReasoning MIB Browser see so many OIDs from my device as I expected well. I then downloaded the device's MIB table (which is in .txt format) and then use Paessler import that MIB table to see those OIDs and found they're the same as what iReasoning MIB Browser shows. That's, basically, the Paessler and MIB Browser agree each other with the MIB OIDs taken from the device.

Then, I saved the MIB OIDs into .oidlib format in Paessler. I then import those .oidlib file by PRTG and found the PGTG can show only a small portion of OIDs which can be shown from MIB Browser and Paessler.

How come?

When I used Paessler to open the .oidlib format MIB file, I found the OIDs are normal as I expected, as what MIB Browser shows. At least, it means the MIB file in .oidlib format must be the same as file in .txt format.

So, what's wrong with it?